# Do Yen's modifications of Bellman-Ford algorithm work for DAGs?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, graph-theory, shortest-path, bellman-ford

Bellman-Ford algorithm is useful to solving the single source shortest path problem and has a unique and interesting property of k-hops optimality for every vertex, at kth iteration, which is required for my application. (basically, I want a shortest path of at most k-hops between a pair of vertices)

There are two [wellknown improvements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm#Improvements) for Bellman-Ford due to J. Yen, which supposedly reduce the complexity from O(|V|^3) to O(|V|^3 /4).. i.e. a good savings in computations by a constant factor equal to 1/4  (a factor of 1/2 from each improvement).

However, it appears that at least one of the modifications is not useful for directed acyclic graphs (DAG) since Yen's method essentially depends on dividing the graph into two DAGs, then altering the iterations between the two DAGs, and thereby obtaining an advantage of a factor of 1/2. Is it correct?

On the same lines, it would be greatly appreciated if you can tell whether there are there  any other improvements/alternatives to Bellman-Ford which can find k-hop optimal shortest paths??

Comment: I wonder if this is the kind of question that would better be asked on http://programmers.stackexchange.com (which is for more conceptual questions)?

Comment: or even [Computer Science.Stackexchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and I've posted there in cs.SE.
Should I remove this Q?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yen's modification works fine on DAGs. In fact, if you choose the linear order to be a topological order of the DAG, then it converges in just one iteration. The problem for you is that Yen's modification won't solve your problem, since it requires that edges be relaxed in a particular order rather than simultaneously, which is what you need to find shortest paths with at most k edges.